# Calculating real value

Tags: php, statistics, percentage

I'm trying to run sales report to find which products sold the most, but `sold/available` doesn't really give a real measure of of performance because for example:

```
Product 1: 6 sold of 8 = 75%
Product 2: 232 sold of 500 = 46.4%
```

.. so although `Product 2` is clearly selling well but based on the percentage of sales, its scores low in the report. I'm sure there must be some formula to calculate this but being a non-programmer I haven't come across it, and googling didn't find me anything useful either.

Comment: You can use certain if else statements like if the product has been sold more 100 and precent is 50+ and such. It depends wholly on your wish what to give preference and what not to.

Comment: Actually the formula not depend on the code. Is the math applied to code.

Comment: You're making a little mistake here, from my point of view. You should sum up all the products and calculate the percentage from that: 6 ... 508 ... 1% and 232 ... 508 ... 46%. Could you please give more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question if I get it right is not about programming or about math.

It is about business analysis :-)

You wrote : `is clearly selling well`.

What is your criteria to decide what is WELL?

In different situation and business flows there are many parameters.

For example if your `product 1` price is 1 000 000. - you did huge sales.
and at the same time price of `Product 2` is 0.01 - who told you that `is clearly selling well` ? why is it clear for you?

Another example is frequency and history.
If your `Product 1` was in stock for a while 6 month before with no sales,
and last week you'va sold 6 of 8 - you must get a bonus from your manager.
On another hand, if your `Product 2` last sale (232 items) was 6 month ago. 
and you can sell 0 items during las 6 month. Your boss could decide to fire you.

So what is your question about? :-)))

Maybe you can use formula:
Product 1 = 0.75 (%) * PriceOfProduct1  vs Product 2 = 0.464 (%) * PriceOfProduct2
and compare amount of sales.

but usually there much more than 2 or 3 criterias managers analyse the sales data. there could be some planed volume against real achievements. season factor multiplicator and many others.

So what are yours criteria to say `is clearly selling well` ?

Comment: I didn't mention but adding the time and cost (and profit) to the calculation clearly shows Product 2 is selling well because obviously sales are more therefore profit is more and all in the same amount of time that it took product 1.